# Setting HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR server variable in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, fiddler, server-variables, request.servervariables

I need to set the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR value in the Request.ServerVariables collection. I'm trying with Fiddler (see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211854/how-to-set-value-for-http-x-forwarded-for-manually)).

So I set up a custom HTTP request:

```
GET http://myhost/ HTTP/1.1 http_x_forwarded_for: my.fake.ip.1, my.fake.ip.2 Host: myhost.
```

The request is correctly executed.

But when I debug the code, the Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") is empty.
Where am I wrong?
Is Fiddler the correct tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header you are sending should be `x-forwarded-for`.  The `Request.ServerVariables` are exactly what it says  **server variables**.  It does not just contain the http headers sent in the request.

When placing the header values into server variables IIS creates a name for the variable that is *based* on the header name but is not the name verbatim.  It converts all characters to uppercase, replaces all `-` with `_` and adds the prefix of `HTTP_` to header name to create a server variable name.  The prefix is added to prevent arbitary headers aliasing other fixed server variable names.